# Pyodbc slow on table with a million+ rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc

The question is when querying my database using **pyodbc** it can take around a minute to return my data. This table in my database is hovering around a million + rows. How can I speed this up? I've tried setting values for the main columns in the table and it still is slow. I've also tried limiting the data returned to no avail. Is there something else out there that is faster or I can I possibly change something to make the following faster? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=mydb;UID=myuserid;PWD=mypass')

class Visual(object):

  def get_resource_ids(self, *xargs):
    resource_ids = []
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from operation where status = 'C' and  workorder_type = 'W' and workorder_base_id = ? and workorder_lot_id = ? and workorder_split_id = ? and workorder_sub_id = ? and rownum <= 10", xargs[0], xargs[1], xargs[2], xargs[3])
    try:
      return [dict(count=str(index), resource_id=row[6]) for index, row in enumerate(cur, 1)]

    except ValueError:
      print "Error"
    finally:    
      cur.close()
      conn.close()
```

Comment: When you say "I've also tried limiting the data returned" do you mean that you've tried retrieving just the column(s) of interest instead of doing `select *`?

Comment: This is what I am doing to limit the data returned  "rownum <= 10" @GordThompson

Comment: If a query with `rownum <= 10` takes just as long as a query without that constraint then the "rownum" column is apparently not indexed. Is "operation" a table or a view? Is "rownum" an actual column or a derived column? Does the underlying table have indexes on all of the columns included in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes each column in the where clause has a index attached to it @GordThompson

Comment: What database are you using? IIRC from my Oracle days, `rownum` is a keyword that doesn't prevent full table scans. Have you done an `EXPLAIN` on the query? My guess is that it's something in your table design, not `pyodbc`.

Comment: If you are using Oracle, read up a bit more on `ROWNUM`: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: I agree with you FlipperPA it seems to be how my table structure is setup running PyODBC on a fresh table works great. @FlipperPA

Answer (score 0):

Basically due to poor table design this was self inflicted not a Pyodbc issue. Moral of the story design tables better.